# Powershell - Test-Path error handling

Tags: shell, powershell

Can someone help me with this error handling of this script.
I basically need to test to see if a file exists - if it does, copy it if not - dont throw an error.  The problem i have is if the files does not exist i get an error when i test here:

```
$DMZ_Test_File1 = Test-Path $DMZ_File

Cannot bind argument to parameter 'Path' because it is null.
```

Full code - all the rest works fine when the file exists

```
$DMZ_File = Get-ChildItem 'DMZ_Drive:*.xml' | Where {$_.LastWriteTime -gt (Get-Date).AddHours(-24)} -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
$DMZ_Test_File1 = Test-Path $DMZ_File
If ($DMZ_Test_File1 -eq $true) {Copy-Item $DMZ_File LAN_Drive:\}
Else {Write-Host "File does not exist"}
```

Please excuse my rudimentry coding! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to check if `$DMZ_File` is not equal to `$null`. Therefore you've to extend the second line of your code to:

```
$DMZ_Test_File1 = if ($DMZ_File) { Test-Path $DMZ_File }
```

See this [link](http://www.thomasmaurer.ch/2010/07/powershell-check-variable-for-null/) for further examples/information.